# Undefined step when executing feature file or individual scenario - Step undefined

Tags: intellij-idea, maven-3, cucumber-jvm, cucumber-java

Undefined step when executing feature file or individual scenario
Script running properly using Runner file, however when try to run feature file directly then I am getting issue **"Step undefined
You can implement this step using the snippet(s) below:"**
Also I noticed that test-classes missing in target folder when feature file run directly

I tried invalidate cache option, which not worked

This is project structure

[image]

Glue
[image]

Target Folder structure when feature file executed directly

[image]

Target Folder structure when executed using Runner File

[image]

Comment: The same structure is working perfectly in eclipse i.e. when feature file executed directly

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Open Run/Debug Configurations, here under before launch, remove Build option and select Build Project and Apply

[image]

Now Run -- no more "Undefined Steps"
Here Build Project option compile the entire project, whereas Build options compile the module.

https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/running-cucumber-tests.html#cucumber-run-configuration

https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/run-debug-configuration-cucumber-java.html#before-launch-options